# I want to link one task as successor to multiple task in MS project

Tags: ms-project, scheduling

I want to link one task as successor to multiple task in MS project. How it can be done quickly? There is one successor and 50 predecessors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Organize/filter your schedule so that all 50 predecessors are
   located together.
2. Add the Successors column to your task table.
3. Enter the ID of the desired successor into the successors list of the first of the 50 predecessors.
4. Select the cell you just entered, then use the autofill cursor (black square at lower right corner of cell) to pull the successor ID into each of the remaining 49 predecessors.  (If predecessors are not adjacent, then use copy/paste, though you'll need to paste 49 times.)

This won't work if your predecessors already have other successors and your intent is to add a new one.  In that case dump the successors column to Excel, manipulate by concatenating strings, then copy/paste back to MSP.

Answer (score 0):

All predecessors can be added at once by entering into the Predecessor field a comma separated list of IDs of the predecessor tasks.

For example, enter "2,3,4,6,7,8" to make those 6 tasks predecessors to the current task with the default finish-to-start relationships.

See [Predecessors (task field)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Predecessors-task-field-5a5ea9c2-14e6-4be7-9a3d-d8b6cba10cab) for more details about link types.